# Allow optional GraphQL data in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to build a Type in my `gatsby-node.js` file that supports an optional value. Which I think is done with `[String!]!`.

**How can I load the new Type that I've created inside `gatsby-node.js` on `home.js`?**

gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require('path');
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
    const { createTypes } = actions;
    const typeDefs = `
        type markdownRemark implements Node {
            frontmatter: Features
        }
        type Features {
            title: [String!]!
            description: [String!]!
        }
    `;
    createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

pages/home/home.js:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query HomeQuery($path: String!) {
        markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
                features {
                    title
                    description
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

home.md:

```
---
path: "/"
features:
    - title: Barns
      description: Praesent commodo cursus magna vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    - title: Private Events
      description: Praesent commodo cursus magna vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    - title: Food and Drinks
      description: Praesent commodo cursus magna vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    - title: Spa
      description: Praesent commodo cursus magna vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
---
```

This needs to work so that if the `features` array inside `home.md`'s front matter is empty, then GraphQL doesn't throw an error.

Please don't tell me to always include at least one value in the array, because this isn't practical, my solution needs to support no values in my array.

I've spent two hours going through documentation/issues in circles trying to find a working solution, please can someone save me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields):

> - `String!` means that the field is **non-nullable**, meaning that the GraphQL service promises to always give you a value when you query this field. **In the type language, we'll represent those with an exclamation mark**.
> - `[Episode!]!` represents an array of `Episode` objects. Since it is also non-nullable, you can always expect an array (with zero or more items) when you query the field. And since `Episode!` is also non-nullable, you can always expect every item of the array to be an `Episode` object.

The exclamation point `!` in GraphQL means **non-nullable**, so `[String!]!` means that there is a non-null array of non-null strings.

If you want a field to be optional, just leave it as it is without exclamation points `!`. For example `[String]` means that the array can be null, or any of the string values inside it can be null.

I'm also not sure that you want to be using an array in the first place, since `title` and `description` of a feature should surely just be a single string?

As per the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#nested-types), I think what you're looking for is this:

```
const typeDefs = `
    type markdownRemark implements Node {
        // Use custom frontmatter type
        frontmatter: Frontmatter
    }
    // Define custom frontmatter type
    type FrontMatter {
      // Nullable array of Feature elements
      features: [Feature]
    }
    // Feature has nullable fields title and description
    type Feature {
        title: String
        description: String
    }
`;
```

This means that frontmatter has a field called `features` that can be null (optional) and if it does exist, is an array of `Feature` objects. It can be empty, but if any `Feature` objects exist, each `Feature` has a nullable (optional) `title` and `description` field.